# How to go to error-line of missing event handler in XAML?

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2015, uwp-xaml

**Question edited after being corrected by comments. The problem is only with one type of error. So it's not such a big deal. But since the question is up already...**

When I click on an error  in the error list - the cursor goes to the erroneous line in code or XAML. Not so if the error is of the type `'MainPage' does not contain a definition for 'button_Click' ...` in XAML, though the error list does have the error line number.

Is there a way to get that in too? If not automatically - is there some button that can be clicked to go to the error?

Comment: Double clicking the error seems to be working for me.  Is it a specific type of error that it isn't working for?

Comment: I don't think so, since the actual error can be pretty arbitrary often. Like for a simple example, if you leave a element open like `<Button` on like line 5, then line feeding 20x and and adding another closed element, then the error will report on line 25 instead of 5. So it's a catch-22 situation.

Comment: @BradleyUffner `'MainPage' does not contain a definition for 'button_Click' ...` I now see that other errors do work. It's only this one that doesn't.

Comment: @ChrisW. See my previous comment.

Comment: I'm assuming "button_Click" does actually exist somewhere logical then? If so it sounds like it may just be time to del your bin/obj folders and restart VS.

Comment: @ChrisW. No. It actually does not exist. I copied some XAML from one project to another and want to go over all of the missing event handlers and create them. And it would be easier if I could go through them quickly.

Comment: Well, I was able to recreate your problem with a missing event handler, but unfortunately I can't find any way to work around it.  This seems like a visual studio bug, you may want to report it.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Thanks for verifying it's not only on my computer.

Comment: The errors cannot  go to are generated after solution build.